# How to resolve "could not locate file in lookup" reading id_rsa.pub?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

in an Ansible playbook, I'm trying to read the default public key into a variable to be used later.
Here's my yml:

```
- hosts: hostsGroup
  become: false
  vars:
    publicKey: "{{ lookup('file', lookup('env','HOME') + '/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

The script breaks with the following error:

```
fatal: [redacted-ip]: FAILED! => 
{"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ lookup('file', lookup('env','HOME') + '/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, 
original message: An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'file'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, 
original message: could not locate file in lookup: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"}
```

The file is confirmed to exist in that location.

Is there a better way? or What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting [the documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_lookups.html):

> Lookups occur on the local computer, not on the remote computer.

To get the content of the remote file, you can use a task like this:

```
- name: get remote file contents
  command: "cat {{ ansible_env.HOME }}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
  register: key
```

You can then access the contents like this:

```
- name: show key contents
  debug:
    var: key.stdout
```

But! Note that here I'm using `ansible_env.HOME`.  This is populated by Ansible when gathering facts, and it will represent the value of the `HOME` environment variable from the perspective of whatever user Ansible used to authenticate.  If you're using things like `become_user`, the value will not change to reflect the new user.

Comment: I downvoted because the `slurp` module is preferred over the `command` module for such use case.

Comment: I'm not sure that it is.  It is an *option*, certainly, but for getting plain text content into a variable a `command` task is often much simpler. It depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: `slurp` is platform agnostic and exists solely for the purpose of "fetching a base64- encoded blob containing the data in a remote file". `command` is so generic that it is an _option_ for _replacing_ several modules, i.e. `command` is an _option_ for performing a `mysqldump` however the `mysql_db` module is preferred for the purpose (`state: dump`).

Comment: Thanks man, and just a heads up, there's a typo error on you answer is `ansible_env` and not `ansbible_env` :D

Comment: @Krismorte thanks for catching the typo; I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in [Lookup plugins documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html)

> Like all templating, these plugins are evaluated on the Ansible
>   control machine, not on the target/remote.

You can use [slurp module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/slurp_module.html) to get the content of your remote key.

Comment: Note that when the file has been slurped it's a Base64 Encoded string that needs to be piped through `b64decode`.

Comment: @BenH Yes, absolutely. It's indicated multiple times in the module documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned become: false. meaning you want to force the ansible_user lookup in /home/ directory.
However the playbook was looking for the key in a root location: could not locate file in lookup: /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Assuming you want the get publick key for the ansible_user, your playbook is escalating to the root user every time it connects to the remote server + lookup searches in local machine not the remote ones.